# How to remove all non-numeric characters (except operators) from a string in Python?

Tags: python, strip

I would like to remove all non-numeric characters from a string, except operators such as `+,-,*,/`, and then later evaluate it. For example, suppose the input is `'What is 2+2?'` The result should be `'2+2'` - keeping only the operator symbols and numeric digits.

How can I do this in Python? I tried this so far, but can it be improved?

```py
def evaluate(splitted_cm):
    try:
        splitted_cm = splitted_cm.replace('x', '*').replace('?', '')
        digs = [x.isdigit() for x in splitted_cm]
        t = [i for i, x in enumerate(digs) if x]
        answer = eval(splitted_cm[t[0]:t[-1] + 1])
        return str(answer)

    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
```

Comment: `expression = ''.join([x for x in splitted_cm if x.isdigit() or x in '+=/*'])`

Comment: **Do not use `eval()` for anything that could possibly receive input from outside the program in any form. It is a critical security risk that allows the creator of that input to execute arbitrary code on your computer.**

Comment: Please note that this is **not a discussion forum**. I [edit]ed the question to [remove noise](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721) and ask the [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236) clearly. That said: I'm a bit confused here. It seems as though the code doesn't correspond to the problem requirement at all. The actual evaluation of the expression is a **separate process** which you don't seem to be asking about, but which is embedded into the code attempt.

Comment: Also: **what should happen** for an input like `4 cats + 3 dogs`? What does happen?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I actually would like to get the output after evaluating that `2+2`. Your edit makes it people think, I want the output just like after removing all letters and other chars except numbers and operators.   

`- Also: what should happen for an input like 4 cats + 3 dogs?`

My current environment does not need such an expression. No args given will be like `4 cats + 3 dogs`. The thing I'm working on will only give strings such as `"what is 2+2?"`, `"what is 3+3"`. Just like those.

Comment: "I actually would like to get the output after evaluating that 2+2" Okay, but that is a *separate step to the process*. If you want to ask about how to improve that part of the code, therefore, it is a *separate question*, and including it here makes the question too broad.

Comment: Woops! I'm sorry if its two questions but I actually intend to make a single function which does it all. I mean functions are like a group of actions or statements right? So there will be lot of things.... uh I dunno to explain. If it was 2 questions then let it stay as you edited. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex and `re.sub()` to make substitutions.

For example:

```
expression = re.sub("[^\d+-/÷%\*]*", "", text)
```

will eliminate everything that is not a number or any of `+-/÷%*`. Obviously, is up to you to make a comprehensive list of the operators you want to keep.

That said, I'm going to paste here @KarlKnechtel's comment, literally:

**Do not use eval() for anything that could possibly receive input from outside the program in any form. It is a critical security risk that allows the creator of that input to execute arbitrary code on your computer.**

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll make sure to not use eval in codes which I intent to recieve input from strangers.